# Is looking at "paparazzi" pictures of public figures counted as "spying"?

Tags: fiqh, image

Many pictures may have been taken without their consent and some images might even expose their awrah!

But with the social media, these images are bombarded to us on our screens even without our consent.

So, is looking at "paparazzi" pictures of public figures counted as "spying"? What if one is intentionally searching for them to look at?

Comment: "Spying" might have many meanings. What do you exactly mean? Looking at 'awrah? looking in the "house" of a person without his consent?... Consider checking [ask] end elaborating your post by adding information. Note that as a registered user you'd be able to edit your post.